# Android Brightnes of Color programarically

Tags: android, colors, brightness

How can I modify the brightness of Color programatically?
for example with Java AWT Color convert to HSB modify brightness and convert to Color.
In Android how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The API provides several methods to convert ARGB and HSV in the [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) class.

Added Code snippet:

```
float []hsvBlue = new float[3];
Color.colorToHSV(Color.BLUE, hsvBlue);
int rgbBlue = Color.HSVToColor(hsvBlue);
```

Comment: For example? I seen the API but, how can I do it?

Comment: how does changes apply to  screen?

Comment: That's a question that opens a wide range of discussion about what and how you are drawing to the screen.